# Fecha limite, Laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo un sistema en el cual se suben reportes mensuales, los reportes deben ser subidos durante el mes actual, si son subidos el siguiente mes deberán ser marcados como tardíos o no a tiempo. En mi table reports, tengo un campo status que es insertado depende a si lo subieron a tiempo o no, como extra si no fue a tiempo se registra un incidencia.

He intentado con carbon y funciona, pero el detalle es que utilizo el siguiente código y no funciona al 100%.

```
$limite = Carbon::now()->endOfMonth();
$creacion = Carbon::now();

if($creacion < $limite) {
    $status = 'a tiempo';        
}else{
    $status = 'fuera de tiempo';   
    Incidence::create([]);
}

die();
```

El `die();` solo es porque he estado haciendo pruebas, mi problema es que estoy tomando como limite el ultimo día del mes actual, entonces si suben un reporte que es del mes de agosto, el primer día de septiembre lo sigue marcando como a tiempo debido a la mala validación, lo único que se me ha ocurrido es poner un campo de fecha en el formulario y así validar de que mes es el reporte, pero me pidieron que fuese automática la fecha. Alguien tiene una idea de como podría lograrlo?

Este es mi table reports:

```
Schema::create('reports', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');    
    $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies');    
    $table->bigInteger('syndicate_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('syndicate_id')->references('id')->on('syndicates');    
    $table->integer('c_situation');
    $table->text('current_comment');    
    $table->bigInteger('manager_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('manager_id')->references('id')->on('managers');  
    $table->integer('c_manager');
    $table->text('comment_manager');    
    $table->integer('casual_workers');
    $table->integer('plant_workers');               
    // campo a capturar
    $table->string('status');   
    $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');    
    $table->softDeletes();    
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: El problema como tal va más allá de tu código, necesitas validar de alguna forma a qué mes corresponde el informe. Por lo visto, no tienes cómo hacer esto. ¿Qué pasa si alguien tarda más de 3 meses en subir sus informes? ¿Qué pasa si subieron el informe de junio y luego el de mayo?

Comment: Para validar que suban el reporte mes tras mes, hago una comparación entre el numero de empresas que se le asignan a la persona y el numero de reportes que suben dicho mes, la única opción viable que he conseguido es agregar el campo fecha, pero quiero pensar que existe alguna otra cosa que se pueda, por eso fue mi pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según explicas, tu problema radica realmente en que **no sabes cómo manejar a qué mes corresponde el archivo que está subiendo la persona**. Tu problema no tiene **NADA** que ver con la fecha límite, como lo indicas en el título.

**Realmente hay muchas soluciones, y depende de cómo lo desees enfocar y/o tu nivel de conocimientos de programación, y/o los requerimientos del proyecto.**

Veo según lo que explicas en otros comentarios, que tampoco quieres agregar campos extra en el formulario, como el campo de fecha correspondiente (que creo que es la solución más sencilla), entonces te quedan algunas otras opciones:

- Tal vez los usuarios deban escribir el año y mes al que corresponde el informe en el nombre del archivo o en los meta, y lo lees cuando lo suban.
- Suponiendo que sea un archivo de excel, por ejemplo, puedes abrir el archivo, leer un campo dentro de este e identificar a qué mes corresponde. (demasiado complejo para mi gusto).
- Mostrarle al usuario los meses que le faltan por subir informes, y habilitar su campo correspondiente de carga de archivos, con eso no debes agregar campos adicionales, simplemente iteras. Por ejemplo, si le falta subir actualmente los meses de mayo y julio, le muestras dos campos, indicandole a qué corresponden, y mostrándole de antemano que su informe de mayo está fuera de tiempo (asumiendo que el mes actual sea julio).

Mi opción favorita: la última. En términos de UX le estás mostrando todo lo que tiene pendiente, y le estás especificando a qué mes corresponde cada campo, de esta forma el usuario no debe pensar mucho, y el sistema tampoco.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios detalles por corregir:

- no debes comprar Carbon::now() con Carbon::now()->endOfMonth() porque siempre te dara el mismo mes:

```
ejemplo:
   now = '2019-09-24'
   endOfMonth = '2019-09-30'

siempre que compares esas 2 fecha estaran dentro del mismo mes.
```

- Deberias en el formulario de subir los reportes tener un selector con el mes del reporte, y que el usuario eliga que mes quiere subir y luego con ese dato si compras.

```
    // en tu formulario deberias tener
    select = 2019-01
             2019-02
             ...
             2019-09

    $mes_seleccionado = Carbon::create(2019, 08, 1, 0, 0, 0); // solo nos importa año y mes
    $mes_actual = Carbon::now();

    if($mes_seleccionado->isSameMonth($mes_actual)){
      // esta a tiempo
    } else {
      // esta fuera de tiempo
    }
```

te dejo la doc de carbon para que la estudies un poco mas a detalle: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison

Comment: Si de hecho es fue un de las soluciones que pensé en hacer, el problema es que la fecha se debe capturar en automático no agregar un select al formulario si no con el campo created_at o la fecha actual debe ser comparada con otro dato, mas aun no se cual usar.